# Is it possible to directly copy data from Numpy array to MonetDB?

Tags: python, numpy, monetdb

Since Numpy arrays map to C arrays and MonetDB is using C arrays as its [storage model](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/MonetDB/Architecture/Storagemodel), is it possible to load data from in-memory Numpy arrays into MonetDB? This would save a round-trip to disk, i.e. writing the data from the Numpy array to disk and bulk loading it from disk into MonetDB. I'm aware of [embedded Python in MonetDB](https://www.monetdb.org/blog/embedded-pythonnumpy-monetdb) but I'd rather have embedded MonetDB in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official MonetDBLite for Python implementation supports this. See the examples for inserting data. https://www.monetdb.org/blog/monetdblite-for-python